# Can S4 object be set as reactive variables?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I'm developing a shiny app, where I want to set an S4 object as a global varibale. But I get an error message:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

I wonder if S4 objects can not be set as reactive values in shiny.

My code is here

```
ensemblObj=reactiveValues()
ensemblObj$ensembl=useMart(biomart='ensembl')
ensemblObj$archieves=listEnsemblArchives()
ensemblObj$specials=listDatasets(ensemblObj$ensembl)
```

The error occurs at the last line. useMart(biomart='ensembl') will create an object that link to a server, and listDatasets(ensemblObj$ensembl) wants to get all available datasets from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this within a reactive environment, e.g.

```
ensembleObj <- reactive({
  out <- list()
  out$ensembl = useMart(biomart = 'ensembl')
  out$archieves = listEnsemblArchives()
  out$specials = listDatasets(out$ensembl)

  out
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and no error message. But how can I use the out$ensembl variable out of the reactive expression?

Comment: Please read on [reactivity in shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html). You may need to use `isolate`, but it's not clear what you're trying to achieve from your question, sorry. @XiaoWen